# I need help comparing Absolute Value charts. Similarities and differences. Image is below

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

[image]
Hey guys I need help with my homework regarding Absolute values. I need to compare the similarities and differences in these two charts. If you guys could help out I’d greatly appreciate it. Image is down below. :)

Comment: What do you mean by *compare and contrast the images*?

Comment: My teacher said things like find characteristics similar and different about them

Comment: The question is a bit vague.  That said, observe that the graph of $g$ is obtained by reflecting the graph of $f$ in the origin.  Therefore, I suggest you compare distances of the vertices and intercepts from the origin for similarities and the actual locations of the vertices and intercepts for differences.

Comment: Thank you guys!